# How can i prevent concurrent request for findByName method?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and And Spring Data for develop an application that using microservice architecture. In my scenario a microservice has a repository like that

```
    @Repository
    public interface JobInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<JobInfo, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<JobInfo> {

        boolean existsByNameAndOrganization(String name, UUID organization);

        boolean existsByIdNotAndNameAndOrganization(UUID id, String name, UUID organization);

    }
```

and service method that use this repository

```
    @HystrixCommand
    public JobInfo save(JobInfo entity) {
        if (repository.existsByNameAndOrganization(entity.getName(), entity.getOrganization())) throw new ValueAlreadyExistException(entity.getName());
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
```

When i call this service method concurrently **existsByNameAndOrganization** method returns false. And first thread can create a record in database. After that second Thread can create another record with same name. What is proper way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `save()`, call [`EntityManager.persist()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-), which will throw `EntityExistsException` if the entity already exists.

You could also create a unique constraint in mysql, indexed by name and organization.

Comment: Hi @jingx. Neither name nor organization primary key. I think for this reason EntityExistException doesn't throw.

Comment: A unique key constraint is different from a primary key: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: The unique constraint, as @jingx said, will prevent this. If you schema is generated from a JPA-annotated entity, use `@Column(unique=true)` for the `JobInfo.name` field.

Comment: Ok. I have a field deleted for soft delete. If I will annotate field for unique i can use this name for only one record. What do you think about this?